# How to programmatically call Route in Akka Http

Tags: scala, akka-http

In Akka Http, it is possible to define the route system to manage a REST infrastructure in this way, as stated here: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/overview.html

```
val route =
      get {
        pathSingleSlash {
          complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`,"<html><body>Hello world!</body></html>"))
        } ~
          path("ping") {
            complete("PONG!")
          } ~
          path("crash") {
            sys.error("BOOM!")
          }
      }
```

Is there a way to programmatically invoke one of the route inside the same application, in a way that could be similar to the following statement?

```
val response = (new Invoker(route = route, method = "GET", url = "/ping", body = null)).Invoke()
```

where `Response` would be the same result of a remote HTTP call to the service?

The aforementioned API it's only to give an idea of what I have in mind, I would expect the capability to set the content type, headers, and so on.

Comment: Do using http request count as a solution you'd like to see?

Comment: Why do you even want to  make a REST call to your application from your application ?

Comment: I wuould prefer not to let it call itself through HTTP request if possible. As for the reason, I want my application to be wrapped inside both a web server (then use the route the “normal” way) and a daemon that responds to a message broker inbound message.

Answer (score 2):

In the end I managed to find out the answer to my own question by digging a bit more in Akka HTTP documentation.

As stated here: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/routes.html, the `Route` is a type defined as follows:

```
type Route = RequestContext => Future[RouteResult]
```

where `RequestContext` is a wrapper for the `HttpRequest`. But is true as well that a `Route` can be converted, implicitly or not, to other function types, like this:

```
def asyncHandler(route: Route)(...): HttpRequest ⇒ Future[HttpResponse]
```

Hence, it is indeed possible to "call" a route by converting it to another function type, and then simply passing a `HttpRequest` build ad hoc, receiving a Future containing the desired response. The conversion required a little more time than the rest of the operations, but it's something that could be done while bootrstrapping the application.

**Note**: the conversion requires these imports, as stated here: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/introduction.html

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem("my-system")
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher
```

But these imports are already mandatory for the create of the service itself.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for unit tests, you can use [akka-http's test kit](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/testkit.html).

If this is for the application itself, you should not go through the route, you should just invoke the relevant services that the controller would use directly. If that is inconvenient (too much copy-pasta), refactor until it becomes possible.

> As for the reason, I want my application to be wrapped inside both a web server (then use the route the “normal” way) and a daemon that responds to a message broker inbound message.

I have an application that does something like that actually.

But I came at this from the other way: I consider the broker message to be the "primary" format. It is "routed" inside of the consumer based purely on properties of the message itself (body contents, message key, topic name). The HTTP gateway is built on top of that: It has only a very limited number of API endpoints and routes (mostly for caller convenience, might as well have just a single one) and constructs a message that it then passes off to the message consumer (in my case, via the broker actually, so that the HTTP gateway does not even have to be on the same host as the consumer).

As a result, I don't have to "re-use" the HTTP route because that does not really do anything. All the shared processing logic happens at the lower level (inside the service, inside the consumer).

Comment: This is actually a very good alternative, thank you very much! But doing so I would have to write my own “routing” for the message broker to the actual method myself, am I right? I mean, then both the HTTP routing system and the message broker infrastructure would be based on an internal “broker” right?

Comment: Yes. In my case, I only have a handful of message types. And the "routing" is very simple. Each handler can of course further drill down based on individual message parts as required.